# Сервер для веб-разработки

Tags: php, xampp, openserver, wamp

Посоветуйте сервер для разработки на PHP. Использовал XAMPP, WAMP и OpenServer. Хочется чего-нибудь одновременно простого и красивого. Требований особо нет, главное чтоб поддерживал PHP7 и MySQL.

Comment: Надо не "простое  и красивое" ставить, а то, что максимально приближено к боевым условиям...

Comment: Есть предложение указать ОС.

Comment: Я использую Xampp. Для меня просто и красиво, установлена версия с PHP7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как вариант можно воспользоваться встроенным сервером, предоставляемым дистрибутивом PHP. В этом случае вам не потребуется ничего, кроме PHP.

```
php -S localhost:4000
```

В результате содержимое текущей папки будет доступно по http://localhost:4000. Если права текущего пользователя позволяют вам занимать 80 порт, можно запустить сервер и на 80 порту

```
php -S localhost:80
```

Тогда можно обращаться http://localhost/

Можно указать не только текущую, но и произвольную папку, например, www

```
php -S localhost:4000 -t www
```

При помощи параметра -c можно указать путь к php.ini

```
php –S localhost:4000 -c /etc/php.ini
```

При желании, вы можете даже вещать с этого сервера во вне (например, если требуется показать результаты по локальной сети, для продакшена его конечно лучше не использовать)

```
php –S 0.0.0.0:4000 -c /etc/php.ini
```

Comment: как в этом случае быть с MySQL?

Comment: @Никита Просто ставите отдельно штатный дистрибутив с mysl.com, расширения для работы с ней подключаете через php.ini. Проблем обычно нет.

Answer (score 2):

1. Установить [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/)
2. Собрать для него конфиг на [puphpet.com](https://puphpet.com)
3. *(опционально)* Поставить плагин [vagrant-hostmanager](https://github.com/devopsgroup-io/vagrant-hostmanager) для автоматического обновления `hosts` (`vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostmanager` в консоли)
4. *(опционально)* Дописать какие-то подготовительные скрипты, алиасы и т.п.
5. `vagrant up` в директории с конфигом

Звучит страшнее, чем это есть на самом деле. Главные, для меня, плюсы в том, что:

- С готовым конфигом подготовка окружения займет пару минут
- Получаем маленький *(ну может не очень)* линукс со всеми его преимуществами и *без лишних страданий*

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com).

Из преимуществ: очень легко настраивать, быстрый, написан на Go.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, caddy понравился.

Answer (score 2):

[Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead) - основан на vagrant, но имеет свой простой конфиг.
В результате установки будет Ubuntu 14.04 с уже установленным ПО:

- Git
- PHP 7.0
- HHVM
- Nginx
- MySQL
- MariaDB
- Sqlite3
- Postgres
- Composer
- Node (With PM2, Bower, Grunt, and Gulp)
- Redis
- Memcached
- Beanstalkd

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос некорректный. Веб сервер — сервер, принимающий HTTP-запросы от клиентов. То что вы перечислили XAMPP, WAMP — платформы для разработки, которые включают в себя веб сервер.

Если вам нужен php7 и mysql - поставьте себе php7 и mysql.
Если вам нужен веб сервер ­— nginx, apache, [php built in](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.commandline.webserver.php), [etc](http://google.com.ua/?q=web%20server) к вашим услугам.